# Trying to use fs.chmod with node.js

Tags: node.js, serial-port, chmod, ubuntu-13.10, fs

I have this device that will be connected to a computer, and the system i'm developing depends a lot on that device. However, since it will be installed in different places then they might use one usb port or another, and in my case, everytime i plug in the device i have to do a chmod 777 for it to work.

So, i made this file with possible ports the device could be connected to, and it goes like

```
/dev/ttyUSB0,/dev/ttyUSB1,/dev/ttyUSB2
```

I read it with this function

```
var puertoLect = function(callback){
  //Busca en el archivo ports la lista de puertos probables donde se encuentra el modem receptor
  fs.readFile('ports.txt', 'UTF-8', function (err, data) {
    if (err){
      console.log(err);
    }else{
      callback({data:data});
    }
  });
}
```

And then I use this function to split it into an array and do a chmod for each value of the array.

```
var puertoEnable = function(){
  puertoLect(function(puertos){
    var singlePort = String(puertos.data).split(',');
    for(var i=0;i<singlePort.length;i++){
      fs.chmod(singlePort[i], '0777', function (err){
        if(err){
          console.log(singlePort[i]+': Not Enabled');
          console.log(err);
        }else{
          console.log(singlePort[i]+': Enabled');
        }
      });
    }
  });
}
```

What i'm trying to do with this latest function is test if it works. So that if it finds the exact port then it will enabled it and let me know it did, and if it doesn't, just tell me it didn't. However it ends up returning this:

```
undefined: No se pudo Habilitar
{ [Error: EPERM, chmod '/dev/ttyS24'] errno: 50, code: 'EPERM', path: '/dev/ttyS24' }
undefined: No se pudo Habilitar
{ [Error: ENOENT, chmod '/dev/ttyUSB0'] errno: 34, code: 'ENOENT', path: '/dev/ttyUSB0' }
undefined: No se pudo Habilitar
{ [Error: ENOENT, chmod '/dev/ttyS25
'] errno: 34, code: 'ENOENT', path: '/dev/ttyS25\n' }
```

I don't know what EPERM or ENOENT mean, however, when I tried to do this, the device was not connected (on purpose), because the files ttyS25 and ttyS24 already exist in "/dev". And ttyUSB0 will only appear when i connect the device.

So, I have to try and find a way to check the path to see if the file i'm trying to chmod exists. If it does, then do the chmod and return a variable with the path so i can use it in my serialPort configuration.

If anyone could help i'd appreciate it.

Comment: `EPERM` is "operation not permitted".  `ENOENT` is "file not found".  You can check whether a file exists with [`fs.exists()`](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_exists_path_callback).

Comment: i just added a function to detect whether or not the file exists. and if it exists then it will try to "chmod" it however i still get the EPERM error for them. How can I solve it?

Comment: Are you sure you are allowed to change the permissions on the devices?  Maybe you need root permission?  Have you tried running your script with `sudo`?

Comment: { [Error: EPERM, chmod '/dev/ttyS24'] errno: 50, code: 'EPERM', path: '/dev/ttyS24' }

Comment: well, every time i have to try the system i do have to run i.e. "sudo chmod 777 /dev/ttyUSB0" and i think it's normal for chmod to need root permission. Is there a way to set root password as a parameter to fs.chmod or fs.chmodSync?